# Comparing elements from two 2d-arrays in C without strcmp

Tags: c, string, compare

I am creating a spell-checker in C. I have a dictionary array which is a 2d array. So each word in the dictionary takes a row in the 2d array. In the same way, my input array is also a 2d array. I want to check the spelling of the rows/words in my input array.  **I cannot use strcmp**

An example of input array
['boy','girll','.','friend','  ']-can contain spaces,punctuation and words. We only care about spelling words
if a punctuation/space is compared against a word,we ignore it and move onto the next word.

example of dictionary
['boy','girl','cow'...]-all are words

My code is:

```
 for (int a = 0; a < MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1; a++)
  {

    for (int b = 0; b < MAX_DICTIONARY_WORDS; b++)
    {

        if(tokens[a]==dict_token[b])
        {
          printf("correct");
        }
        else
        {
          printf("wrong");
        }

    }


    }
```

The output is all "wrong". Though 5 out of the 6 word input should be correct.

Comment: Can you post more of the code? For instance, where are `tokens` and `dict_token` declared?

Comment: Have a look at [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [MVCE].

Comment: We need to see what `tokens` and `dict_token` are in order to help.

Comment: I would add that you are going about this wrong way. You're comparing characters in two arrays that have no apparent correspondence to each other. Reduce your data set to a few example the demonstrate your problem and post those. Generally, you want to iterate over words in the input and then search for them in the dictionary. Better if the dictionary is some kind of binary tree, but can you use a sorted array of pointers to words and `bsearch` to perform a binary search.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso updated

Comment: I don't see your declarations of tokens and dict_token. Also, the reason they are all comparing wrong right now is probably because you are comparing pointers, which in this case is always false because they point to different structs

Answer (score 0):

Every test returns false because the comparison you're using,

```
if(tokens[a]==dict_token[b])
```

is comparing two pointers that are never going to point at the same address, because, the `tokens` you are testing are in a completely separate bit of memory to the `dict_token` dictionary that you are comparing them with.

You need to pass the two pointers `tokens[a]` and `dict_token[b]` to a comparison function that will perform a letter-by-letter comparison, and which will return one value when it finds a difference between them, and another when it gets to the end of both without finding a difference. In other words, you need to write an implementation of `strcmp`.

Comment: could you show some code for example? it is easier to understand that way

Comment: I've done my best to word the answer in such a way as to help you write the function without writing it for you. Give it a try! You will make mistakes, and learn things.

Comment: i created another nested for loop to compare  letter wise. But it is inefficient and more importantly prints our wrong/correct power of 3 times. Could you give some hints?